# Consulta web mapping en javascript y consulta sobre servidor

Tags: nodejs, aplicación-web

Tengo un servidor del cual quiero tomar datos atmosféricos: temperatura, humedad y contaminación. La idea es representar estos valores en un mapa según la zona teniendo varios dispositivos en diferentes lugares y mandar las lecturas cada cierto tiempo a un servidor, luego, con los datos recogidos pintar un mapa, por ejemplo, si ciertas zonas pasan cierto grado temperatura pintarlo amarillo, sino azul, o ir bajando tonalidades. Lo mismo para la humedad y contaminación.

¿El servidor tendrá capacidad para soportar todo esto? pues haré datos predictivos usando algoritmos de data mining o big map... Si conocen librerías en js o módulos para estas tareas pues el servidor está en nodejs. También la cuestión del mapa: ¿Qué librerías te dan flexibilidad en cuanto la personalización de la misma? Como es una carga pesada, se actualizará periódicamente y no quiero que se congele o se caiga el servidor. A esto último iba, ¿cómo calcular el consumo o los requisitos mínimos del servidor para implementar esto?

Postdata: Veo que existen muchas librerías de web mapping, pero no puedo estar probándolas todas. No sé si habrá librerías o módulos en js o nodjs para el data mining y, como el tema del clima es un calculo pesado, cuanta memoria o capacidad debería tener el servidor teniendo en cuenta que solo se usará un dispositivo y se emularán unos 4 o 5 solo para la presentación de una beta.

¡Ojo! no pido que me hagan el trabajo sino si alguien ha hecho algo parecido y pueden recomendarme o prevenirme de ciertas cosas.

Comment: Respecto al tema de librerías de mapas : ¿Quieres algo sencillo y rápido? `Leaflet, mapbox, ...` ¿Quieres algo más elaborado? `Openlayers`. Respecto a los algoritmos, creo que si lo que buscas es optimizar un elevado trabajo de cálculo, JavaScript no es el lenguaje, puedes realizar tus algoritmos en scripts de python y ejecutarlos desde nodejs obteniendo un valor de retorno.

Comment: Eso estaba pensando , python ya tiene librerias optimizadas para la mayor parte de esos algoritmos ,y en cuando a librerias acabo de ver una , gmaps , con el cual parece que podré hacer lo que quiero.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo OpenLayers 3 con el que puedes especificar entre muchas otras, el sistema de referencia del mapa, el sistema de referencia de los datos, realizar conversiones de coordenadas... http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

Comment: Estás mezclando muchas cosas en una sola pregunta. Es mejor que elimines esta pregunta y hagas preguntas pequeñas y concretas. Si vas a tratar con datos en tiempo casireal pero no son muchas estaciones ni parámetros casi cualquier servidor te va a valer. Cualquier cosa basada en estadística para hacer predicción atmosférica te dará resultados muy pobres, en general (dependiendo muchísimo de lo que quieras hacer, claro está). Los algortimos los puedes entrenar externamente (offline) y que tu servidor solo use los parámetros obtenidos offline. Pero lo dicho, abre otras preguntas más concretas.